# Occurrence of of a word at the end of string

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays

```
array1 = ["e4dfda158c82cc931e2479e32bde42defacebook", "5824fb40c4a97e21ef9715ea69c1cfb9twitter", "6da098061f82c215f37a4949b1555e26linkedinpage"];

array2 = ["facebook", "twitter", "linkedin", "xing", "weibo", "instagram", "googleplus", "pinterest"];
```

I want to compare these 2 arrays and to get output like the following

```
output = ["facebook", "twitter"]
```

Comparison is based on checking the presence of every element in 'array2' in array1(ie at the end of the string). 
I have tried it using multiple for looping but not working for me, is there any better way using Underscore.js, lodash.

Tried

```
array2.forEach(function(data) {
    array1.forEach(function(data2) {
         n = data2.indexOf(data);
         if(n!=-1) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `array2` for those words satisfying the condition that there is some element in `array1` that ends with that word:

```
array2 . filter(word => 
    array1 . some(string => 
        string.endsWith(word)
    )
)
```

You could use the underscore or lodash equivalents, but there's really no reason to unless you have browser support issues (such as IE).

Comment: Thank you so much, its really helped. Can you give me an underscore.js way of doing my multiple foreach example. 

ie array2.forEach(function(data) {
    array1.forEach(function(data2) {
         n = data2.indexOf(data);
         if(n!=-1) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
})
Only for studying purpose.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf returns -1 only in the case the substring is not found. You probably want to check for the offset being data2.length() - data.length() or suchlike.